# How to generate more strings from one string

Tags: php

I have a string like "**i hate 25**", and I'm trying to make variations like **"i hate 24", "i hate 23"** so on.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'I hate'
$len = 50;
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
  echo $string.$i;
}
```

for random

```
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    {
      echo $string.rand(0,50);
    }
```

is this like you want? if not describe more

Comment: but for this i know where is the number...but if i dont kwow exactly where is the numeric in a string then how to create more string?

Comment: give some more output for ur demo.

Comment: $var="3 is less than 5" is string...then i have to create something as 1. 2 is less than 5 2. 6 is less than 7. etc..

Comment: actually its problem for  generting more multiple choice answers from correct ans but correct answer is string

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to replace any instance of a number in a string with another instance? If so, you could try the preg replace function (this requires a knowledge of regular expressions though, which are a *very* indepth topic. This only covers the surface...)

```
$word = "I hate 24";
$out = preg_replace("#[0-9]+#", "25", $word);
echo $out; //I hate 25
```

Here, the string `"#[0-9]+#"` is a special series of characters that tells PHP "replace one or more instances of a digit in a row, with the number 25

This is only a *very* simple example though. For more info I recommend the site here - http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html